# What is the best local structure for Go open source repository development?

Tags: go

I'm trying to debug Go implementation of ethereum([link](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)), because my core interest is in developing new consensus algorithm (i.e. modify the open source Go code from github).

However, I'm having problem with the location/path of the source code. When I put the folder(i.e. `go-ethereum`) outside of the `$GOPATH` and then try to compile&debug `geth`(`go-ethereum/cmd/geth/main.go`) it shows the following error: `Use of internal package is not allowed.`

From that error message, I figured out that the import `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum` was not importing my source, and instead it was getting code from internet(like other libraries). Which of course is definitely what I shouldn't do when I'm trying to modify the `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum` package code.

So, my workaround was to clone the source code into `$GOPATH/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum` and followed [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/27649/54814), and Goland IDE started compiling&debugging without error (wasn't able to `go build ./cmd/geth/main.go` though due to error `undefined: configFileFlag...`)

Thereby now I've got a working debugger that can debug with my source code modification, but this doesn't look like ideal source code structure.

The question is:

Is putting source code inside `$GOPATH`(because of internals) a proper approach? If so, what if I was using `go-ethereum` package from another project?(Fortunately I'm not, but I'm curious) Do I have to stash&revert changes I made to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the folder structure you ended up with is the right one.

Code should be under `$GOPATH/src` as you describe.

But note that `$GOPATH` is not a fixed folder in your system, you can have multiple projects under different folders and change the value of `$GOPATH` accordingly depending what you are working on (or have multiple console terminals open, each with its own `$GOPATH` value).

Comment: Thanks, is there any program/package for this purpose? For example, python has pip&virtualenv which is used for $PYTHONPATH, package separation.

Comment: If you don't need different version of Go itself, just changing the GOPATH variable would be the easiest. But if you are looking for something similar to virtualenv there are many tools out there, like https://github.com/DamnWidget/VenGO